# How can I get my files off Heroku without using git clone?

Tags: heroku

I messed up my git repo on Heroku really bad, so I rolled back my Heroku release.

So example...

```
v100 = Rollback to V98
V99 = BAD COMMIT / REPO
V98 = CURRENTLY RUNNING / ROLLED BACK TO
```

When I do a heroku git:clone -a [myapp], I get v99 cloned, not v98 even though v98 is the one running on Heroku. Is there any way I can get the v98 release files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `git checkout sha1-hash` to go to any commit you made.

Comment: I don't have those commits in my repo anymore due to a combination of force pull and force push.

Comment: Unless you have garbage collected them, use `git reflog` to see all commits that are still present. They are usually retained for 30 days.

Comment: I force pushed a bad copy of the repo.